# Adding new output column to custom data flow component SSIS

Tags: ssis

I'm trying to add new output column using synchronous custom data flow component(below is the code). While testing I found that input columns I added are not getting displayed in Output columns only the new added column is getting displayed. I'm not sure where problem is. Please help!

```
    Public Overloads Overrides Sub ProvideComponentProperties()
    Dim input As IDTSInput100 = ComponentMetaData.InputCollection.New()
    input.Name = "Input"

    Dim Output As IDTSOutput100 = ComponentMetaData.OutputCollection.New()
    Output.Name = "Output Rows"
    Output.Description = "Output rows with unique row ID appended."

    'Adds new column RowID to output columns list
    Dim rowIDColumn As IDTSOutputColumn100 = Output.OutputColumnCollection.[New]
    rowIDColumn.Name = "Row ID"
    rowIDColumn.SetDataTypeProperties(DataType.DT_UI8, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    Output.SynchronousInputID = input.ID
```

Thanks in advance
Sai

Comment: This code does not add new input **column**, it adds new input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my bad! for Data flow components only new columns will be displayed in the advance editor, but when we take the output arrow and attach to destination(like excel or file or db) then it shows all the columns including the input columns and newly added columns in the mapping tab of destination editor. :)